# CSS > (selector) not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why is this piece of code not working? Only the li items in the first ul in the #menu should be red.

```css
.l-branding .l-region #menu > ul li {background: red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the li items in the first ul in the #menu should be red.

Then you need to use [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type) or [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child) selector to make *the first ul* red:

```css
.l-branding .l-region #menu > ul:first-of-type li {background: red;}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o1muekkj/